# dropwizard and jetty-config files

Tags: jetty, dropwizard

Where do I have to put jetty specific configurations in dropwizard, such as

- jetty-context.xml
- jetty-env.xml
- ...

?

I do not have a src/main/webapp/WEB-INF directory, so what do I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't.

Dropwizard encapsulates most of the jetty configurations on its YAML configuration file. [Reference](http://www.dropwizard.io/1.0.5/docs/manual/core.html#configuration)

For others (context etc.) dropwizard has its own way of handling them programmatically. I highly suggest going through dropwizard's [Getting started](http://www.dropwizard.io/1.0.5/docs/getting-started.html) document as well as the user manual.

Comment: Thanks! Achieved what I needed by adding Listeners in the initiliaze(Bootstrap) method.

Comment: Your first link is dead.

Comment: Fixed it. Thanks.